# Transition jQuery addClass and removeClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to achieve an overlay on divs when i hover them.
Basically i'm adding a class on mouseover and removing the class on mouseleave.
The problem is that i cannot make a transition since the main effect of the class belongs to the :after pseudo element.
I'm actually targeting the div with a placeholderclass called .img-target

CSS

```
.img-overlay{
height: 100%
width: 100%
transition: all 1s ease;
}

.img-overlay::after{
content:"";
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(window).ready(function() {

$(".img-target").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('img-overlay',1000);

});

$(".img-target").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("img-overlay");

});
});
```

I've already tried to apply a transition to the :after and to the .img-target but nothing seems to be working.
Any ideas? :)

P.S. unfortunately using after pseudo element is actually the only way to overlay the div becouse of the theme structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the `:after` pseudo element does not have an initial state

```js
$(window).ready(function() {
  $(".img-target").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('img-overlay', 1000);

  });

  $(".img-target").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("img-overlay");

  });
});
```

```css
.img-target {
  position: relative;
  background-color: gold;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.img-target::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.img-overlay::after {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="img-target"></div>
```

if you are only using jQuery for the mouse in and our detection you can use CSS instead `.img-target:hover::after {...}`:

```css
.img-target {
  position: relative;
  background-color: gold;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.img-target::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.img-target:hover::after {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="img-target"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you that did the trick :)
Is there a way to set the animation on removeClass?

Comment: Yes!, @soldier, that was my bad, we just need to move `transition: all 1s ease;` to the initial state.

Comment: Thanks by the way, i didn't know i could use :hover::after :)

Comment: Solved! I used same proprieties as img-overlay:after on img-targer:after but aplying a fully transparent color!
Thank you for everything! :)